# Variable not defined on VBA about socket

Tags: mysql, sql, vba, sockets

I'm making an edit to a project on VBA that uses a Socket to send information to a program on Netbeans on a specific server.

I did not write the code. I'm trying to understand what the original programmer did.

I have many forms, and a few send information with that socket. I'm trying to do the same with another form.

The error is

> "Variable not defined".

In all the project in any moment there is a declaration of the object/variable named "Socket", but in the forms that originally runs the connection you can make any operations with it, like `Socket.Close`, `Socket.RemoteHost = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"`, `Socket.RemotePort = "xxxx"` and `Socket.Connect` and there is no problem.

I have `Option Explicit` on the beginning, but that same option is on the other forms.

I've looked the flow of the execution with F8 to see if a method or something where the variable is declared, but, or I'm missing something or there is no definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your `Socket` variable is declared as a `Public` field in your form's code-behind.

Forms are class modules with a visual designer. Being class modules, when you work with one you're working with an *instance* of the class.

If you declare `Public Socked As Object` in any class module (i.e. any `ThisWorkbook`, `Sheet1`, `UserForm1`, or `Class1` module), then yes that object is `Public`, but that doesn't make it *global*: the public field *belongs* to the *instance* of the class it's declared in.

That makes the `Socket` identifier *when used anywhere other than in the form's code-behind*, effectively an undeclared variable - kudos for using `Option Explicit` here to catch this mistake at compile-time, otherwise that would have very likely gone unnoticed until run-time, where the undeclared `Socket` local variable would have been some `Variant/Empty` value, and *something, somewhere* likely wouldn't have liked it and would have raised some error, potentially very far from the actual source of the problem!

You have several options.

#### 1. Make `Socket` an actual global variable

`Socket` currently belongs to what I'll call `UserForm1`. Since other components need this piece of data, you could expand its scope by moving the declaration to a *standard module* (.bas):

```vb
'Module1.bas
Option Explicit
Public Socket As Object
```

Now just remove the declaration from `UserForm1` and everything should "just work".

Except, it's a global variable: everyone everywhere can overwrite this object reference at any time.

This isn't ideal.

#### 2. Make the other code consume the `Socket` where it lives

`Socket` belongs to `UserForm1`. Depending on how/whether you're instantiating that form, you might be able to treat it like global state, because all `UserForm` modules have a `VB_PredeclaredId` hidden attribute set to `True`, which is exactly how you're able to do this:

```vb
UserForm1.Show
```

When you do that, the `UserForm1` object instance gets created by VBA at the `.` dereferencing operator, and then the `Show` method is invoked. **If the instance doesn't self-destruct**, then when execution returns after the form is *hidden* (**not** unloaded), then you can access everything `Public` about it:

```vb
Dim theSocket As Object
Set theSocket = UserForm1.Socket
```

Now this obviously comes with a major caveat: you need to take steps to ensure VBA isn't going to re-spawn a brand new instance (with a brand new `Socket` reference, set to `Nothing`) when the `.` dereferencing operator runs in that instruction.

You can do this by handling the `QueryClose` event and explicitly cancelling the destruction of the instance:

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = VbQueryClose.vbFormControlMenu Then
        Cancel = True
        Me.Hide
    End If
End Sub
```

If you have an `OkButton` doing something like this:

```vb
Private Sub OkButton_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Or worse, something like this:

```vb
Private Sub OkButton_Click()
    Unload UserForm1
End Sub
```

Then change it to this:

```vb
Private sub OkButton_Click()
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

This is critical: you MUST `Hide` the form, not `Unload` it, and you can't let it be destroyed before execution returns - the calling code *needs* to be able to use exactly the same instance that the user has been interacting with.

#### 3. Take the control yourself

`UserForm1` is a class, like any other. `New` it up yourself instead of leaving VBA in charge: take the exact same precautions as described above, but now **pretend there's no default instance**:

```vb
Public Sub DoSomething()
    With New UserForm1
        .Show

        Dim theSocket As Object
        Set theSocket = .Socket

    End With
End Sub
```

See my [UserForm1.Show](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) article for more information & details.

---

#### 4. Use a separate `Socket` object

If the form's `Socket` object has no business being used outside that form, then maybe it would make more sense for the other code to also define and setup a `Socket` to play with?

Variables should be as tightly-scoped as possible, *especially* when we're looking at shared resources like a socket connection: if different procedures `Set` this socket to different things, then the only purpose of that variable being `Public` is to avoid the keystrokes of declaring it everywhere you need a socket, and that is abusing global state and *will* bite you in the rear end, one day or another.

Pragmatically speaking, a form has no business knowing how to wire-up a socket anyway: there should be a dedicated module for that, and everyone that needs to talk to a socket should go through that module.

Comment: That's very very helpful!! However, I can't find where its declarated the object in all the forms. I've been looking everywhere, but somehow the declaration must be inherent in some package or some like that (that's kindof my conclusion). I think I will just declare it on the form that I'm working on and that's it.
EDIT: I'm thinking on a declaration private on the class of the form. However, if I quit that form and enter on another: Would it be re-declarated? Like, I should un-declarate it or something if I quit the form or something?
PS: Your answer is very very helpful, thank you so much!

Comment: UPDATE: I've found the problem and UGH! it was a loooot simplier than I thought. The problem was on the interface of the form, where the only thing a had to do is put a WinSock icon and recall it with the name "Socket". On that way, when the form is executed, it creates the Socket and etc.

Thank you very much anyway!!